# Can a valid FOL formula be falsifiable?

Tags: logic

Suppose I have a FOL formula that I can prove is valid. Does the definition of validity exclude the possibility that a formula is falsifiable?

Here's an example:

```
exists x, y. (p(x, y) -> (p(y,x) -> forall z. p(z,z)))
```

If I perform validity check, it turns out that the negation is not satisfiable because you derive the following:

```
forall x, y. (p(x,y) and (p(y,x) and exists z. not p(z,z)))
```

However, if I define p to be `not equal`, then I can see that p(z, z) should resolve to false. Then, there exists an x, y such that the whole formula is falsifiable, because `not equal` returns true for any unique pair of x and y, and false always for z.

Comment: By definition, a formula is valid if and only if it is true in every model. A formula is falsifiable if it is false in some model. So a valid formula cannot be falsifiable.

Comment: The top formula is logically valid, anyway. We can reason by cases. If we have a model where $\forall z p(z,z)$ holds then the formula is true in that model. In a model where $\exists x \lnot p(x,x)$ holds, as witnessed by some element $c$ of the model, the formula is true if we let $x$ and $y$ be $c$.

Comment: That's what I thought. Valid formulas should not be falsifiable. Can anybody comment on my example though? Does that not sufficiently falsify that formula?

Comment: What part of your example falsifies the formula? In other words, what particular model do you believe makes the original formula false? Remember that $x$ and $y$ can be the same element of the model - different variables do not have to be replaced with different elements.

Comment: Just give some values to x and y with p defined as not equal and you can see that there is a falsifying interpretation.

So, 0 and 1 for x and y and any z should do. that would mean the formula could evaluate to p(0, 1) -> p(1, 0) -> p(0, 0). That should resolve to: true -> true -> false.

Comment: Did my example not work? Is it an incorrect interpretation somehow? Looks falsifiable to me.

Comment: Your original formula is valid ... and the negation of it is falsifiable ... so what is the issue?

Comment: @AdamMiller: the $\exists$ quantifier asks if there are values of $x,y$ that do make the predicate true - not whether there are values that make it false. Take $ x= y = 0$ to make the predicate true - so the overall formula is true in your model.   The definition of falsifiable is different, it refers to truth in a model, not whether someone could choose bad values for the existential quantifier.

Comment: Well, each of the p evaluations for x and y do evaluate to true, so I don't see your point. I'm not trying to see it be true, I already know that there are true interpretations for it. What I'm looking at is a formula that is valid, which is verifiable by the semantic method, but for which I have shown there is a falsifiable interpretation. I thought falsifiability <=> invalidity, so isn't this an issue?

Comment: But the part $\forall x, y \ ((x \ne y) \land (y \ne x) \ldots )$ is *unsatisfiable*: in every domain it is impossible that $x \ne y$ for every $x$ and $y$, because at least $x=x$ and $y=y$.

Comment: @Adam Miller: I recommend that you number your formulas. Because you talk about a formula, then about its negation, then that a formula is falsifiable. I am completely lost which formula you are talking about. And use LaTeX, please.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The original formula is the first one. The negation is the second. The fact that my example produces a true expression in the negation means that the above is falsifiable. The question is whether or not my example is correct, and whether it changes validity. It is said a formula is valid if and only if it's negation is not satisfiable, and because of duality, a valid formula should not be falsifiable.

let p x y = not ( x = y )

In regular ocaml code, p(0, 1) would return true. Therefore, p(0, 0) would return false. In which case, the expression is true -> true -> false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it can't.

The negation of the original formula is:

> $\forall x, y \ [p(x,y) \land p(y,x) \land \exists z \ \lnot p(z,z)]$.

You are suggesting an interpretation with $\ne$ for the binary predicate $p$ that satisfy this formula (which is *unsatisfiable*, being the negation of a *valid* formula).

If we replace $p$ with $\ne$ we get:

> $\forall x, y \ [(x \ne y) \land (y \ne x) \land \exists z \ (z = z)]$.

But in no not-empty domain $D$ whatever we can satisfy it: consider $a \in D$ and instantiate the leading quantifiers with $a$ to get:

> $(a \ne a) \land (a \ne a) \land \textbf{ exists z } (z = z)$.

Thus, it is not true that: "for every $a \in D, \ldots$".

But this holds for every $D$ (that is not-empty) and thus there is no domain where the suggested interpretation of $p$ will satisfy the above formula.

In your original paraphrasing, you missed that the negation in front of the formula $p(z,z)$, when used with $\ne$ in place of $p$, resolves to just equality, in which case $z = z$ is always true.